# why sync() not take effect in netty for ChannelFuture

Tags: java, netty

I'm learning Netty, I does not really understand the sync method for ChannelFuture, here is my Examples:

```
public class EchoServer {
    private final int port;

    public EchoServer(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("Usage: " + EchoServer.class.getSimpleName() + " <port>");
            return;
        }

        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        new EchoServer(port).start();
    }

    public void start() throws Exception {
        // final EchoServerHandler serverHandler = new EchoServerHandler();
        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();

        try {
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.group(group).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class).localAddress(new InetSocketAddress(port)).childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {

                @Override
                protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                    // ch.pipeline().addLast(serverHandler);
                }
            });

            ChannelFuture f = b.bind().sync();
            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            group.shutdownGracefully().sync();
        }
    }
}



public class EchoClient {
    private final String host;
    private final int port;

    public EchoClient(String host, int port) {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void start() throws Exception {
        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();

        try {
            Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
            b.group(group).channel(NioSocketChannel.class).remoteAddress(new InetSocketAddress(host, port)).handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {

                @Override
                protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                    // ch.pipeline().addLast(new EchoClientHandler());
                }
            });


            ChannelFuture f = b.connect().sync().addListener(future -> {

                   if(future.isSuccess()) {

                       System.out.println(port + " bind success");

                   } else{

                       System.err.println(port + " bind fail");

                   }

               });

            System.out.println("aaa");

            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            group.shutdownGracefully().sync();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: " + EchoClient.class.getSimpleName() + " <host> <port>");
            return;
        }

        String host = args[0];
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        new EchoClient(host, port).start();
    }
}
```

My question is , whatever I remove the sync() in EchoClient.class for ChannelFuture f = b.connect().sync() or not, the result is always:
aaa
8811 bind success

in my opinion, if I add sync(), the result should be:
8811 bind success
aaa

as the main thread will wait for the channel to connect,

if i remove the sync(), the result should be：
aaa
8811 bind success

as the connect() is asynchronous

why I'm wrong?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your question . can you please reword it ?

Comment: @NormanMaurer Ok, as English is not my native language, maybe I've not described the question well, I mean for the code
ChannelFuture f = b.connect().sync().addListener，
the sync() method, in my opionion, will ensure the connect() finish first, and then execute the codes below, so I think 
System.out.println(port + " bind success"); 
will be executed first, and then execute 
System.out.println("aaa");

but the result is :
aaa
8811 bind success

it's not like what I think， the System.out.println("aaa"); has been executed first

Comment: answered below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sync()` will unblock as soon as the operation finishes and then the `EventLoop` will notify all the attached listeners to the `ChannelFuture`. As your main-thread and the `EventLoop` thread are different there is a high-possibility that you will see the `System.out.println(...)` in the main-thread before the one in the `ChannelFutureListener`